# How to search for a specific font in a Word document with iterop

Tags: fonts, interop, ms-word, find, readonly

I use something like this:

```
doc.Content.Find.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
```

but when I step through the code the Name property doesn't change.
thanks.

---

I'm working with VS2010 and MS Word 2007 and I want to find and replace all "Times New Roman" fonts with "Arial".

Here's what happens:

```
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Documents docs = wordApp.Documents;
doc = docs.Open(fileName, Visible: false);
doc.Content.Find.ClearFormatting();
doc.Content.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();

// Here the value of Find.Font.Name and Replacement.Font.Name is ""

doc.Content.Find.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
doc.Content.Find.Replacement.Font.Name = "Arial";

// The value of Find.Font.Name and Replacement.Font.Name still "" !!!

doc.Content.Find.Execute(Format: true, Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```

Comment: Can you show us more of the code? For starters, in the snippet here, you set the name property to a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, but no you don't get a new Find object each time you use dot notation. The problem is you shouldn't use Doc.Content.Find in this kind of situation. Instead you have to create a new Range object and use its Find. Something like this:

```
Word.Range range = doc.Range(0, doc.Content.End);
```

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but you might want to double check the assertion that you don't get a new Find object when you reference through dot notation like that.

Comment: Ooops, edit was thrown out. Reposting....   Glad you solved your problem, and you may be right about the FIND object not being new each reference (though I was able to replicate your "font name always returns blank" problem, which would seem to be indicative of that. But I was also able to search perfectly fine using the Content.Find object just as I described. Alternatively, you could have just done  set Rng = Doc.Content.Duplicate

Comment: Yes that's confusing, you can set Find.Font properties but you can't read them.

Comment: can you post sample , complete  code? with it's full namespace resultions, I couldnt understand at first whichever was `Word.WdReplace..`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to obtain a FIND object and then use it, when you refer to the object via dot notation like you have, you're always getting a brand new FIND object, so you'll loose your settings each time.

Something like this

```
With Doc.content.Find
    .clearFormatting
    .Font.name = "blah"
    .Execute .....
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application word;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document doc;

bool found_next = false;
private void search_Replace1()
{
    word = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    doc = word.ActiveDocument;
    word.Selection.Find.Font.Name = "My Font";
    found_next= word.Selection.Find.Execute(Format: true);
    if (found_next)
    {
        word.Selection.Font.Name = "Arial"; 
        //word.Selection.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed;  //change color to red
    }
}
```