# Selecting text by font in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

Is there a way of extracting all lines that are using a particular font (size, is it bolded, font name, etc) in word via C#?

In addition, is there a way to find out what is the font for some text that is in the document?

My hunch is that there are functions in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace that can do this, but I cannot seem to find them.

**Edit:** I am using word 2010.

Comment: I didn't work with MS Word APIs but maybe you can specify the version of Word you work with? This might be relevant, AFAIK *.doc* and *.docx* are very different formats (not sure about the APIs though).

Comment: Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.font(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396909/how-to-search-for-a-specific-font-in-a-word-document-with-iterop might help

Comment: Not sure how I can use ranges to do this. Seems silly to go character by character for this. @oleksii, edited.

Comment: @EknathIyer, How can a range handle different blocks of text (say from 1-6 and 15-20)? (sorry, I don't know much about ranges)

Comment: That was just a starting point for you to look into. If I had known the complete answer I'd have *answered* your question :)

Comment: lol, got it, thanks. I'm sure it will be helpful, but I don't know nearly enough about the API to make use of it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the document [using the `Find` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.aspx) from Word Interop. You can set the `Find.Font.Name` property for a Selection or Range from your document. Note that the `Font` interface has several `Name*` properties for various encodings.

**EDIT**

Here's the equivalent VBA code:

```
Dim selectionRange As Range
Set selectionRange = Application.ActiveDocument.Range

With selectionRange.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Format = True
    .Font.NameBi = "Narkisim" //for doc without bidirectional script, use Name
    Do While .Execute
        MsgBox selectionRange.Text
    Loop
End With
```

The object model from Word Interop is the same, see the link above.

Don't go asking me for C# code now... this is SO, we don't do silver platters. And if you're ever going to do serious work with the Office Interop API, you will need to be able to read VBA code.

Comment: Find returns the first match? After that, do I have to change my range?

Comment: No, you can call `Execute` again until it returns false. *The method* changes the range.

Comment: Can you please provide the code this does this? I don't really understand what you mean.