# Change word document body font and Footnotes font

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

I have MS Word document how can I change it body font to "Arial" and Footnotes font to "Times New Roman" using C# ,  (Interop.Word or any free library).

I Did Search a lot before posting this Question.. But find nothing.

I found this Question but it dose not really help

[How to search for a specific font in a Word document with iterop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396909/how-to-search-for-a-specific-font-in-a-word-document-with-iterop)

Comment: Did you not find MSDN documentation on Microsoft Word Interop?

Comment: No. I think I didn't figure it out how to change an Exist word document fonts

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some sample code. I have set the font for both body text and footnote text. The code reads "test.doc" from C drive.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace Word
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                
            Application wordApp = new Application();
            string filename = @"C:\test.doc";

            Document myDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filename);

            if (myDoc.Paragraphs.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Paragraph p in myDoc.Paragraphs)
                {
                    p.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri";
                    p.Range.Text = "I have changed this text I entered previously";
                }
            }

            if (myDoc.Footnotes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Footnote fn in myDoc.Footnotes)
                {
                    fn.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
                }
            }

            myDoc.Save();
            myDoc.Close();
            myDoc = null;
            wordApp.Quit();
            wordApp = null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are looking for MSDN documentation on using Word Interop then [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157880.aspx) is the link.

Comment: thank you, But I already have the text and paragraphs in my document. I want to change the font name of that text.

Comment: @user3570328: modified my code to what you asked for. You gotta actually look at the MSDN documentation. Pretty good examples also.

Comment: Thank you.. it is work for the first part 
(bad for me I found it is not working with another language as Arabic)

- and in this code you change the footer font Not the Footnotes font.
so can you give me a little more Help here

Comment: Sorry I read it as footer (my bad). I have modified my answer as per your question. Cheers!